# Memcached crashes / spikes to 100% CPU with EC2, Nginx

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, php-fpm, memcached

I have a strange issue with PHP 7.4, Nginx, PHP-FPM and Memcached on EC2

Randomly the server will spike from 1% CPU to 100% and continue using everything it can until I reboot it.

Rebooting just the Memcached service fixes this and then it'll happen again after a couple of days at random. It doesn't happen at a particular time and there is no obvious change in the access logs (e.g excessive hits to Nginx).

At first I thought It could have been unclosed connections from PHP FPM but it doesn't seem like that.

It's hard for me to debug because the sever slows to a crawl while this issue is occuring.

Memcached config:
Max connections 1000
Cache size 1024M

Server RAM: 4G

How would I debug the issue when it occurs?